# Set up Visual studio library project dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, static-libraries, glew

I'm struggling to find out the proper way to set up dependencies in Visual Studio (i.e. 2015) given the following case:

I have 2 projects:

- Engine: it is a static library project and depends on glfw, glew and opengl .lib files that I specify in "Librarian", "Additional dependencies" section. I also add include and libs directories properly.
- Game: It should only be able to access the API given by Engine project, so I add Engine headers directory to Game include directories and the same for the generated Engine.lib with the additional libraries directory.

At this stage, Engine project compiles successfully.

I hoped that Game project would work too but when I try to compile this project with a simple main.cpp, the compiler shows this error(referencing a file from Engine project):

-- Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

I don't want to include opengl, glew and glfw libraries and include directories to my Game project, since the user shouldn't access to this API.

So... what's the proper way to achieve this (the simpler the better)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a file in ````Game```` is including a header file in ````Engine```` that ````include````s GL/glew.h then indirectly GL/glew.h is included in that file. A way to get around this is usually to move such an include into the source file in ````Engine```` and remove the ````include```` in the header if possible. That way it will only be included by the file using it, and not by every file using that header.

Comment: I guess this is the only acceptable option. However, this implies some little design adjustments in my code architecture since this header (GL20.h) maps required constants such as "GL_VERTEX_SHADER" or "GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER" that are included as constant expresions within a enum (Shader Types) in a header ShaderProgram.h... and if I change its definition to the GL20.cpp, they cannot be used as constant expresions within the aforementioned enum. (among some other changes).
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

> Steps to link a static library to another project in same solution:

Make your `Engine` project a library if it isn't already. Build it.

Right click your solution or one of your projects and go to `Build dependencies -> Project dependencies`. Select your `Game` project in the dropdown, then check the box next to `Engine`. This will let the compiler know that `Game` can't start without `Engine`.

Go to your `"Game" project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories`, make sure you have the location of your `Engine` project's header file here.

Go to `C/C++ -> Code Generation`, make sure both projects use the same Runtime Library as eachother in debug and release.

Go to `"Game" Project properties -> Linker` and put the location of your other project's lib file here.

Go to `Linker -> Input` Add `Engine.lib` or equivalent to this list.

You should have a project linked to a library. Reply to my response if this didn't help.

Comment: That won't solve the problem since the glew header files are missing in game and not the engine headerfiles.